# Warm up on HuggingFace Tensorflow implementation without using Trainer

Tags: tensorflow, huggingface-transformers

I need to inject some warm up steps to replicate results from a paper. I'm currently using HuggingFace's TF implementation and the code I'm working on isn't using a Trainer. The only sample implementations I've found so far are using Trainers and on PyTorch. I've found [WarmUp](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/optimizer_schedules#transformers.WarmUp) but there is no information on how and where to use it.

Here's the base code I'm using:

```
model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(checkpoint, config = config)
model.compile(optimizer = AdamW(learningRate),
                loss = SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                metrics = ["accuracy"]
                )
model.fit(...)
```

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60120043/optimizer-and-scheduler-for-bert-fine-tuning) to create a scheduler and followed the advice [here](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/linear-learning-rate-warmup-with-step-decay/5604/2#:%7E:text=optimizer%20and%20scheduler) to pass the optimizer and the scheduler as a tuple in the optimizer argument:

```
  optim = AdamW(learningRate)
  totalSteps = int(len(trainX) / batchSize)
  warmup = int(totalSteps * .20)
  
  scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(
      optim,
      num_warmup_steps = warmup,
      num_training_steps = totalSteps
  )
  
  model.compile(optimizer = scheduler,
                loss = SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                metrics = ["accuracy"]
                )
```

but I just get an error of

> 'AdamW' object has no attribute 'param_groups'

so I believe that's not the right way to do it. Any pointers to the right direction would be very useful.

Comment: You import adamw from where? tensorflow-addons? or tensorflow?

Comment: @Innat it's imported from tensorflow.keras.optimizers

Comment: try import from tensorflow addons. `tfa.optimizers.AdamW`